# shapes overlay instead of transition in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, transition

I tried to have a beeswarm plot shift datapoint location to no avail. First, I made a simple scatter plot which can transition except x axis overlays on toggling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Transitioning points to randomized values, plus rescaled axes!</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script><style type="text/css">
            /* No style rules here yet */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name='market' value="a" checked/>a 
        <input type="radio" name='market' value="b"/>b
</label> 
        <p>Click on this text to update the chart with new data values as many times as you like!</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 300;
            var padding = 30;

            //Dynamic, random dataset
            dataset = [
                {"id":1, 
                "value":20,
                "group":"a"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":10,
                "group":"a"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":30,
                "group":"a"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":40,
                "group":"a"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":42,
                "group":"a"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":10,
                "group":"b"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":12,
                "group":"b"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":15,
                "group":"b"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":23,
                "group":"b"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":22,
                "group":"b"},
                {"id":1, 
                "value":54,
                "group":"b"}
                ]


            //Create scale functions
            var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                 .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                 .range([h - padding, padding]);

            //Define X axis
            var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                              .scale(xScale)
                              .ticks(5);

            //Define Y axis
            var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                              .scale(yScale)
                              .ticks(5);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);
        draw(dataset.filter(d=> d.group=="a"));


      //////////////////
      //toggle//
      //////////////////
      d3.selectAll("input")
      .on("change",  function() {
          var data_new = dataset.filter(d => (d.group == this.value));
          draw(data_new);
          });

      //////////////////
      //Create circles
      //////////////////
    function draw(dataset) {
         //////////////////
        //Create axis


        xScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.value; })])
        yScale.domain([0, 2])
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                  .scale(xScale)
                  .ticks(5);
        //Create X axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
     .transition(2000)
            .call(xAxis);

        //Create Y axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis);
        //////////////////
        //draw circle

        svg.selectAll("circle")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.value);
               })
               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.id);
               })
               .attr("r", 3)
         .attr("opacity",0.2);

        //update
        svg.selectAll("circle")
        .transition()
                       .duration(1000)  
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.value);
               })
      }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However when apply a similar code for beeswarm plot, the points don't shift location on selection, they just layer on, like the x axis in the first example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
</style>
<label>
        <input type="radio" name='market' value="a" checked/>a 
        <input type="radio" name='market' value="b"/>b
</label>

<svg width="400" height="200"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatValue = d3.format(",d");

var x = d3.scaleLog()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data = [
  {"id":1, 
  "value":20,
  "group":"a"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":21,
  "group":"a"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":30,
  "group":"a"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":32,
  "group":"a"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":42,
  "group":"a"},
   {"id":1, 
  "value":10,
  "group":"b"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":12,
  "group":"b"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":15,
  "group":"b"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":23,
  "group":"b"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":22,
  "group":"b"},
  {"id":1, 
  "value":24,
  "group":"b"}
]
  //default
  draw(data.filter(d=> d.group=="a"));

  d3.selectAll("input")
  .on("change", function()
{
  var newdata = draw(data.filter(d=> d.group==this.value));
  draw(newdata)

}  )


  /////////////////
//draw swarmplot
/////////////////

function draw(data) {

  // transition
  var t = d3.transition()
          .duration(750);


  x.domain(d3.extent(data, d=> d.value));

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
      .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) { return x(d.value); }).strength(1))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 3))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(18))
      .stop();

  for (var i = 0; i < 120; ++i) simulation.tick();

  //axis
  g.append("g")

      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(20, ".0s"));

  //for mouse-over
  var cell = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "cells")
    .selectAll("g").data(d3.voronoi()
        .extent([[-margin.left, -margin.top], [width + margin.right, height + margin.top]])
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
      .polygons(data)).enter().append("g");

  //circle
  cell.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.data.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.data.y; })
      .attr("fill", d => (d.data.Food_Sub_Group))
      .attr("opacity", 0.4);
 //update circle
  cell.selectAll("circle")
        .transition()
                       .duration(1000)  
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.data.x; })

} 


</script>
```

Anything amiss here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference:

In draw function of the first code, you bind data to 'circle' elements. If you have 5 circle elements before and new data size is 5, then no element is added, what changed is only data. If you have 5 circles before and new data size is 6, then with 'enter()' and 'append' function, after execution, you will have 6 elements.

In draw function of the second code, you add new elements. Every call to draw function adds new points. If you have 5 circle elements before and new data size is 5, then 5 elements are added, you will have 10 elements.

What you say 'no shift location' is actually multiple points be plotted in same place(the point seems to be darker) or different places(more points).

See [data binding in d3](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/data-binding-in-d3js) which  may help.

Comment: Is it because it’s using ‘append circle’ instead of ’selectAll circle’ so it's drawing on the same position? How can I bind data to the circle, do I need to run force simulation again? I don’t quite understand the voronoi section, supposedly it’s for mouseover, but when removing the snippet the code no longer works